# how to make plugin not active when in admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing plugin for wordpress and i have already made settings page for admin in dashboard.
now i want to make some kind of button that is available on all pages but admin's pages like login page or 'wp-admin'.
what do you suggest?
Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `is_admin()`  function in wordpress to determine whether the current request is directed to an admin page, so:

```
    if(!is_admin()){
        //YOUR PUBLIC(NON-ADMIN) ONLY CODE
    }
```

[WP codex on this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/)